# Query Optimize or Tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am fairly new to SQL and am a bit out of my depth with the query I have been working on. I need to optimize the below SQL query. Can anyone suggest how to optimize the below query & its efficiency.

```
WITH MAL_BAL AS
  (SELECT
    /*+parallel(2) */
    DATE,
    BPD,
    A.MNO,
    A.BRT,
    A.BRTD,
    BDR,
    B.CDNO,
    B.CGNO,
    B.BT_DR_AMT,
    B.BT_CR_AMT,
    B.BT_DR_NUM,
    B.BT_CR_NUM
  FROM ABC.POST A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC.BALL B
  ON ( A.BRTD = B.BRTD
  AND A.BRT      = B.BRT)
  WHERE DATE  = TO_DATE ('20170131', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND B.BRTD BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ('20170131', 'YYYYMMDD'), - 1),'MM') AND TO_DATE ('20170131', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND BAT_DPST_TYP_CDE NOT IN ('S', 'V')
  AND B.PRCS_CENTRE_CDE     = 'NA'
  ),
  A_LKUP AS
  (SELECT
    /*+parallel(2)*/
    AA.DATE,
    AA.MNO,
    AA.CDNO,
    AA.CGNO,
    AA.DAC,
    AA.PAC,
    CTD_DB_AMT,
    CTD_CR_NUM,
    CTD_DB_NUM,
    CTD_CR_AMT,
    B.BRT,
    B.BRTD,
    CC.M_DC,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_DC IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_DACE,AA.DAC)
    END AS DAC_LKP,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_DC IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_INTCHG_AMT_AT_CDE,DD.PRD_AT_INTCHG_AMT)
    END AS INTCHG_AMT_LKP,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_DC IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_ASSMNT_AT_CDE,DD.PRD_ASSMNT_AT_COD)
    END AS ASSMNT_AT_LKP,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_PC IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_PACE, AA.PAC)
    END AS PAC_LKP,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_PC IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE, DD.PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT)
    END AS PITM_ASSMNT_AT_LKP,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_DC IN ('E', 'P', 'A', 'I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_INTCHG_AMT_AT_CDE, DD.PRD_AT_INTCHG_AMT)
      ELSE AA.PRD_AT_INTCHG_AMT
    END INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_PC IN ('E', 'P', 'A', 'I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_INTCHG_PCT_AT_CDE, DD.PRD_AT_INTCHG_PCT)
      ELSE AA.PRD_AT_INTCHG_PCT
    END AS INTCHG_PCT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_DC IN ('E', 'P', 'A', 'I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_ASSMNT_AT_CDE, DD.PRD_ASSMNT_AT_COD)
      ELSE AA.PRD_ASM_DISC_AT_CDE
    END PRD_ASSMNT_AT_CDE,
    CASE
      WHEN CC.M_PC IN ('E', 'P', 'A', 'I')
      THEN NVL (CC.NPT_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE,DD.PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT)
      ELSE AA.PRD_ASM_PITM_AT_CDE
    END AS PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE
  FROM MP.MALL AA
  INNER JOIN MAL_BAL B
  ON AA.DATE  = B.DATE
  AND AA.MNO     = B.MNO
  AND AA.BILL_TYP = 'MD'
  AND AA.CDNO     = B.CDNO
  AND AA.CGNO     = B.CGNO
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MP.M_T1 BB
  ON AA.MNO = BB.MNO
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MP.N_T1CC
  ON AA.CLG_NUM      = CC.CLG_CF_NUM
  AND AA.CDNO     = CC.CDNO
  AND AA.CGNO     = CC.CGNO
  AND BB.PMF_NPP_NUM = CC.NPP_NUM
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MP.P_T1 DD
  ON AA.CLNO  = DD.CLG_CF_NUM
  AND AA.CDNO = DD.CDNO
  AND AA.CGNO = DD.CGNO
  ),
  APL_CD AS
  (SELECT
    /*+parallel(2)*/
    DATE,
    MNO,
    CDNO,
    CGNO,
    BRT,
    BRTD,
    CASE
      WHEN M_DC NOT IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN DAC
      WHEN DAC_LKP = 'D'
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN CTD_DB_AMT = 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN DAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN ASSMNT_AT_LKP
              WHEN DAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
          WHEN CTD_DB_AMT <> 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN DAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN DAC_LKP
              WHEN DAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
        END)
      WHEN DAC_LKP = 'C'
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN CTD_CR_AMT = 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN DAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN ASSMNT_AT_LKP
              WHEN DAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
          WHEN CTD_CR_AMT <> 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN DAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN DAC_LKP
              WHEN DAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
        END)
      WHEN DAC_LKP NOT IN ('D', 'C')
      THEN DAC_LKP
    END 
    DAC,
    -- PITM APPLY TYPE CODE
    CASE
      WHEN M_DC NOT IN ('E','P','A','I')
      THEN PAC
      WHEN PAC_LKP = 'D'
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN CTD_DB_NUM = 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN PAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN PITM_ASSMNT_AT_LKP
              WHEN PAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
          WHEN CTD_DB_NUM <> 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN PAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN PITM_ASSMNT_AT_LKP
              WHEN PAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
        END)
      WHEN PAC_LKP = 'C'
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN CTD_CR_NUM = 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN PAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN ASSMNT_AT_LKP
              WHEN PAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
          WHEN CTD_CR_NUM <> 0
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN PAC_LKP = INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN PAC_LKP
              WHEN PAC_LKP <> INTCHG_AMT_LKP
              THEN INTCHG_AMT_LKP
            END)
        END)
      WHEN PAC_LKP NOT IN ('D', 'C')
      THEN PAC_LKP
    END 
    PAC,
    INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    INTCHG_PCT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    PRD_ASSMNT_AT_CDE,
    PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE
  FROM A_LKUP
  ),
  MAL_BAL_MALL AS
  (SELECT
    /*+parallel(2) */
    A.DATE,
    A.CLNO,
    A.CDNO,
    A.CGNO,
    A.MNO,
    B.BRT,
    B.BRTD,
    B.BDR,
    A.CPT_ID,
    A.CTD_DB_AMT,
    A.CTD_CR_AMT,
    A.CTD_DB_NUM,
    A.CTD_CR_NUM,
    TRUNC (
    CASE
      WHEN A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT = 0
      THEN 0
      WHEN A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT <> 0
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN C.DAC               = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT - A.CTD_CR_AMT) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.DAC                = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT             - A.CTD_CR_AMT) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_AMT - B.BT_CR_AMT) / (A.CTD_DB_AMT - A.CTD_CR_AMT)) * A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT
          WHEN C.DAC               = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT + A.CTD_CR_AMT) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.DAC                = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT             + A.CTD_CR_AMT) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_AMT + B.BT_CR_AMT) / (A.CTD_DB_AMT + A.CTD_CR_AMT)) * A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT
          WHEN C.DAC = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_AMT    = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.DAC = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_AMT   <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_CR_AMT / A.CTD_CR_AMT) * A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT
          WHEN C.DAC = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_AMT    = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.DAC = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_AMT   <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_DR_AMT / A.CTD_DB_AMT) * A.CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT
          ELSE 0
        END)
    END, 6) BAT_PRD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT,
    TRUNC (
    CASE
      WHEN A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT = 0
      THEN 0
      WHEN A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT <> 0
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN C.PAC                = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_NUM - A.CTD_CR_NUM) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.PAC                 = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_NUM             - A.CTD_CR_NUM) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_NUM - B.BT_CR_NUM) / (A.CTD_DB_NUM - A.CTD_CR_NUM)) * A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT
          WHEN C.PAC                = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_NUM + A.CTD_CR_NUM) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.PAC                 = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_NUM             + A.CTD_CR_NUM) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_NUM + B.BT_CR_NUM) / (A.CTD_DB_NUM + A.CTD_CR_NUM)) * A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT
          WHEN C.PAC = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_NUM   = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.PAC = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_NUM  <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_CR_NUM / A.CTD_CR_NUM) * A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT
          WHEN C.PAC = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_NUM   = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.PAC = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_NUM  <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_DR_NUM / A.CTD_DB_NUM) * A.CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT
          ELSE 0
        END)
    END, 6) BAT_PRD_FEE_PITM_AMT,
    TRUNC (
    CASE
      WHEN A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT = 0
      THEN 0
      WHEN A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT <> 0
      THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE     = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT - A.CTD_CR_AMT) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE      = 'N'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT             - A.CTD_CR_AMT) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_AMT - B.BT_CR_AMT) / (A.CTD_DB_AMT - A.CTD_CR_AMT)) * A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE     = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT + A.CTD_CR_AMT) = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE      = 'G'
          AND (A.CTD_DB_AMT             + A.CTD_CR_AMT) <> 0
          THEN ( ( B.BT_DR_AMT + B.BT_CR_AMT) / (A.CTD_DB_AMT + A.CTD_CR_AMT)) * A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_AMT              = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE = 'C'
          AND A.CTD_CR_AMT             <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_CR_AMT / A.CTD_CR_AMT) * A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_AMT              = 0
          THEN 0
          WHEN C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE = 'D'
          AND A.CTD_DB_AMT             <> 0
          THEN (B.BT_DR_AMT / A.CTD_DB_AMT) * A.CTD_INTCHG_AMT
          ELSE 0
        END)
    END, 6) BAT_PRD_INTCHG_AMT,
    B.BT_DR_AMT,
    B.BT_CR_AMT,
    B.BT_DR_NUM,
    B.BT_CR_NUM,
    CTD_FEE_DSCNT_AMT,
    CTD_FEE_PITM_AMT,
    CTD_INTCHG_AMT,
    CTD_FEE_AMT,
    SUM (b.BT_DR_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY a.MNO, a.CDNO, a.CGNO, a.CTD_DB_AMT, a.CTD_CR_AMT) AS S_BT_DR_AMT,
    SUM (b.BT_CR_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY a.MNO, a.CDNO, a.CGNO, a.CTD_DB_AMT, a.CTD_CR_AMT) AS S_BT_CR_AMT,
    'N'                                                                                                        AS RCLS_FLG,
    C.DAC,
    C.PAC,
    C.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    C.INTCHG_PCT_APL_TYP_CDE,
    C.PRD_ASSMNT_AT_CDE,
    C.PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE
  FROM MP.MALL A,
    MAL_BAL B,
    APL_CD C
  WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE
  AND A.MNO       = B.MNO
  AND A.CDNO       = B.CDNO
  AND A.CGNO       = B.CGNO
  AND B.DATE   = C.DATE(+)
  AND B.MNO       = C.MNO(+)
  AND B.CDNO       = C.CDNO(+)
  AND B.CGNO       = C.CGNO(+)
  AND B.BRT       = C.BRT(+)
  AND B.BRTD   = C.BRTD(+)
  AND A.BILL_TYP   = 'MD'
  AND A.CPT_ID NOT LIKE '%CF%'
  AND A.DATE = TO_DATE ('20170131', 'YYYYMMDD')
  AND A.CPT_ID NOT LIKE 'BTCH'
  )
  --AND A.CLNO NOT IN (5, 6)),

SELECT A.DATE,
  A.CDNO,
  A.CGNO,
  A.MNO,
  A.BRT,
  A.BRTD,
  A.BDR,
  A.CLNO,
  A.CPT_ID,
  A.DAC DACE,
  A.PAC DSCNT_PACE,
  A.INTCHG_PCT_APL_TYP_CDE,
  A.INTCHG_AMT_APL_TYP_CDE,
  A.PRD_ASSMNT_AT_CDE,
  A.PRD_ASSMNT_PITM_AT_CDE,
  A.BT_DR_AMT BP_DB_AMT,
  A.BT_CR_AMT BP_CR_AMT,
  A.BT_DR_NUM BP_DB_NUM,
  A.BT_CR_NUM BP_CR_NUM,
  A.BP_FEE_DSCNT_AMT,
  A.BP_FEE_PITM_AMT,
  A.BP_INTCHG_AMT,
  NVL (B.BP_FEE_ASSMNT_AMT, 0) BP_FEE_ASSMNT_AMT,
  NVL (B.BP_ASSMNT_PITM_AMT, 0) BP_ASSMNT_PITM_AMT,
  NVL (B.BP_ASSMNT_AMT, 0) BP_ASSMNT_AMT,
  NVL (B.CONVNCE_FEE, 0) CONVNCE_FEE,
  NVL (B.SURCHG_AMT, 0) SURCHG_AMT,
  NVL (B.PHRESIA_AMT, 0) PHRESIA_AMT,
  NVL (B.DCC_RBT_AMT, 0) DCC_RBT_AMT,
  A.RCLS_FLG RLCS_FLG
FROM MAL_BAL_MALL A
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC.BBA B
ON A.DATE  = B.DATE
AND A.MNO     = B.MNO
AND A.CDNO     = B.CDNO
AND A.CGNO     = B.CGNO
AND A.BRT     = B.BRT
AND A.BRTD = B.BRTD
WHERE CTD_DB_AMT = S_BT_DR_AMT
AND CTD_CR_AMT   = S_BT_CR_AMT;
```

Note: BBA Table has full access plan (I am working on index of it), apart from that if any other changes required please let me know.

EXECUTION PLAN

```
Plan hash value: 489280008

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                           | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                    |                             |     1 |   437 |   643   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION                          |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                                    |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                              | :TQ10000                    |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     LOAD AS SELECT                                  | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D9682_9E3FE5C2 |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                                   |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                                  |                             |     1 |   111 |   633   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR                            |                             |     1 |    65 |   631   (1)| 00:00:02 |     1 |     4 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                   | POST                        |     1 |    65 |   631   (1)| 00:00:02 |     1 |1048575|  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |        PARTITION RANGE AND                          |                             |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |KEY(AP)|KEY(AP)|  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 10 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | BALL_PK                     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |KEY(AP)|KEY(AP)|  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID             | BALL                        |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |   PX COORDINATOR                                    |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|  13 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                              | :TQ20004                    |     1 |   437 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|* 14 |     HASH JOIN OUTER                                 |                             |     1 |   437 |    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|* 15 |      VIEW                                           |                             |     1 |   276 |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |       WINDOW SORT                                   |                             |     1 |   397 |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|  17 |        PX RECEIVE                                   |                             |     1 |   397 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|  18 |         PX SEND HASH                                | :TQ20002                    |     1 |   397 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 19 |          HASH JOIN OUTER BUFFERED                   |                             |     1 |   397 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  20 |           PX RECEIVE                                |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  21 |            PX SEND HASH                             | :TQ20000                    |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q2,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|  22 |             NESTED LOOPS                            |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  23 |              NESTED LOOPS                           |                             |     1 |   303 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 24 |               VIEW                                  |                             |     1 |   135 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  25 |                PX BLOCK ITERATOR                    |                             |     1 |    89 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWC |            |
|  26 |                 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D9682_9E3FE5C2 |     1 |    89 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  27 |               PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                |                             |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 28 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | MALL_PK                     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 29 |              TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID      | MALL                        |     1 |   168 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|  30 |           PX RECEIVE                                |                             |     1 |    94 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  31 |            PX SEND HASH                             | :TQ20001                    |     1 |    94 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  32 |             VIEW                                    |                             |     1 |    94 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  33 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER                     |                             |     1 |   228 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  34 |               NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                             |     1 |   183 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  35 |                VIEW                                 |                             |     1 |   164 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  36 |                 NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                             |     1 |   217 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  37 |                  NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |     1 |   205 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 38 |                   VIEW                              |                             |     1 |    70 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  39 |                    PX BLOCK ITERATOR                |                             |     1 |    89 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWC |            |
|  40 |                     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D9682_9E3FE5C2 |     1 |    89 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  41 |                   PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |                             |     1 |   135 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  42 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| MALL                        |     1 |   135 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 43 |                     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | MALL_PK                     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2774 |  2774 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  44 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | M_T1                        |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 45 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | M_T1_PK                     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  46 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | P_T1                        |     1 |    19 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 47 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | P_T1_PK                     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  48 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | N_T1                        |     1 |    45 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 49 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | N_PK                        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  50 |      BUFFER SORT                                    |                             |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWC |            |
|  51 |       PX RECEIVE                                    |                             |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|  52 |        PX SEND BROADCAST                            | :TQ20003                    |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,03 | P->P | BROADCAST  |
|  53 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR                           |                             |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,03 | PCWC |            |
|  54 |          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                  | BBA                         |     1 |   161 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q2,03 | PCWP |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   8 - filter("A"."DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "A"."BRTD"<=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "A"."BAT_DPST_TYP_CDE"<>'S' AND "A"."BAT_DPST_TYP_CDE"<>'V' AND "A"."BRTD">=TO_DATE(' 2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  10 - access("B"."PRCS_CENTRE_CDE"='NA' AND "A"."BRT"="B"."BRT" AND "A"."BRTD"="B"."BRTD")
       filter("B"."BRTD"<=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "B"."BRTD">=TO_DATE(' 2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "A"."BRTD"="B"."BRTD")
  14 - access("J"."BRTD"="B"."BRTD"(+) AND "J"."BRT"="B"."BRT"(+) AND "J"."CGNO"="B"."CGNO"(+) AND "J"."CDNO"="B"."CDNO"(+) AND 
              "J"."MRNO"="B"."MRNO"(+) AND "J"."DATE"="B"."DATE"(+))
  15 - filter("CTD_DB_AMT"="S_BT_DR_AMT" AND "CTD_CR_AMT"="S_BT_CR_AMT")
  19 - access("B"."DATE"="C"."DATE"(+) AND "B"."MRNO"="C"."MRNO"(+) AND "B"."CDNO"="C"."CDNO"(+) AND "B"."CGNO"="C"."CGNO"(+) AND 
              "B"."BRT"="C"."BRT"(+) AND "B"."BRTD"="C"."BRTD"(+))
  24 - filter("B"."DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  28 - access("A"."DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "A"."BILL_TYP"='MD' AND "A"."CDNO"="B"."CDNO" AND 
              "A"."CGNO"="B"."CGNO" AND "A"."MRNO"="B"."MRNO")
  29 - filter("A"."CPT_ID" NOT LIKE '%CF%' AND "A"."CPT_ID"<>'BTCH')
  38 - filter("B"."DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  43 - access("AA"."DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "AA"."BILL_TYP"='MD' AND "AA"."CDNO"="B"."CDNO" AND 
              "AA"."CGNO"="B"."CGNO" AND "AA"."MRNO"="B"."MRNO")
  45 - access("AA"."MRNO"="BB"."MRNO"(+))
  47 - access("from$_subquery$_008"."CLG_NUM"="DD"."CLG_CF_NUM"(+) AND "from$_subquery$_008"."QCSJ_C000000000600004"="DD"."CDNO"(+) AND 
              "from$_subquery$_008"."QCSJ_C000000000600006"="DD"."CGNO"(+))
  49 - access("AA"."CLNO"="CC"."CLG_CF_NUM"(+) AND "BB"."PMF_NPP_NUM"="CC"."NPP_NUM"(+) AND "AA"."CDNO"="CC"."CDNO"(+) AND "AA"."CGNO"="CC"."CGNO"(+))

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=5)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 2 because of hint
```

Comment: What "below SQL query" are you talking about?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to optimize it?  Is it running slowly, and if so, how long is it taking and how much data is in the tables?  Have you gathered statistics on the tables?  There are a lot of `Rows = 1` in the explain plan, which is often a sign of stale or missing statistics.

Answer (score 0):

One first trivial step in troubleshooting SQL Queries is to simple remove all 
optimizer hints (`PARALLEL` in you case) and re-run the query to see if the hints are not causing the
performance problems.

Basically there is only very limited possibility to troubleshoot a single query without knowing at least the basic mechanism and meanings of the 
operation of the execution plan.

Fortunately there are extensive resources available in the web.

I'd commend to observe the execution of the query with  [DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sqltun.htm#ARPLS220)

You will get idea where, i.e. **in which operation the database time is consumed** and how **exactly the optimize estimates the carnality**
(through the difference in *Actual rows* and *Estimated rows*).

To nail the problem down, you may also try to simplify you query (*check how many lines have queries other people post on SO*), so that the performance
problem remains.